# Azure Event Hub - Stream Analytics architecture

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I need some help figuring out how to build/optimize my **Azure** architecture for the future.
I currently have a test running that looks like this:
[image]

I am currently sending some kind of data x1 (700k a day) as described in the picture above, the **"Stream Analytics"** service does nothing else but ingesting the data in the database without any aggregations or other processes.
The test is currently running without any problems but I am afraid that I might run into difficulties in the future because I want to connect more data (x2, x3, ...), which will of course increase the amount of data sent.
Now my question:
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set up the **"Event Hub"** and **"Stream Analytics"** service to handle the increasing amount of new data.

1. Currently I have an **"Event hub"** with one partition. Would this be sufficient in the future with increasing data volume and would the Stream Analytics service still be able to keep up with the processing?
2. Should I rather create a separate **"Event Hub"** for each different data type (x1, x2, ...) or should I rather create an "Event Hub" with several partitions?
3. For each data type a separate "Event Hub" with multiple partitions?

I have difficulties in understanding the concept of partitions and how to implement them.

Does anyone have a similar architecture and can give me some advice.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can think of Eventhub partitions as a multi lane highway. A 4 lane highway will have more throughput than a 1 lane highway. The only benefit of a single lane highway is that the processing will happen in sequence (FIFO). But if that is not a mandate/requirement, you should set the partitions to the max(32) to use the complete power of eventhub streaming ingestion. Eventhub will automatically distribute the messages to the different partitions provided the publisher is not directing the messages to a particular partition. You can find the info on partitions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#partitions).

Another option to allow for future scalability on the eventhub is to set the throughput of the eventhub to autoscale [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-auto-inflate) between a min/max value. For example 1TU-4TU.

Similarly, you can set the stream analytics to autoscale [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-autoscale#custom-autoscale---default-condition).

Stream Analytics can process each eventhub partition in parallel, and more partitions increases parallelism. Number of streaming units that a job can use also depends on maximum possible parallelism. An an example, 1 partition eventhub would only allow a max of 6 streaming units. 2 partitions would allow 12 streaming units. Doing the capacity estimation and starting with a reasonable partition count would be better, to handle future scaling requirements.